# Not receiving all serial data

Tags: c#, .net

I've tried everything I can find on the net, and nothing has helped, so I have to turn to you good people for a little enlightening.

I'm using Visual C# 2013, .NET Framework 4.5 (I hope I got the tags correct)

I've been writing embedded code for quite a while and I'm very comfortable with it. This c# stuff is a totally different animal.

I have a program written on an ARM microcontroller that is talking serially to a C# program. I'm 99.9% sure the microcontroller is sending everything correctly. I've used Realterm to look at the data and all seems good but I can't get my C# program to receive all the data the way I think it should.

Both the microcontroller and c# program are set to the same settings (57600 baud, 8 data bits, no handshaking, no parity, one stop bit) Not a big deal there.

My problem is if I set ReceiveByteThreshold to 1, and the program gets one byte and is sent to the ISR (not sure if ISR is the correct term in c# but that's what I'll call it). And this is how I understand it should work.

I have the following code to get the bytes.

`GlobalVars.data_byte` is an `array` of 100 bytes and `bytes_to_read` is set to 100.

```
serialPort1.Read(GlobalVars.data_byte, 0, bytes_to_read)
```

My problem is if I look at the return value of the `serialPort1.Read` function, it bounces between 5 and 13 bytes, but I'm sending 21 bytes from the microcontroller. For some reason it's not getting them all.

Now, if I set `ReceiveByteThreshold = 13` the return vale bounces between 13 and 16. If I set `ReceiveByteThreshold = 14` (or anything up to 21) the return value is a nice steady 21, as it should be.

Am I missing something? I thought the way this should work is if `ReceiveByteThreshold = 1` the program will be sent to the ISR as soon as the first byte is read and

```
  serialPort1.Read(GlobalVars.data_byte, 0, bytes_to_read)
```

would read all the bytes until it sees a stop bit. Meaning it should read all 21 bytes.

I can't simply make `ReceiveByteThreshold = 14` because not all the data I'm sending is 21 bytes long. Sometimes it's only 2 bytes and the ISR would never be triggered.

I hope I made this clear enough.

Comment: you have to loop based on the result of `.Read` (meaning call `.Read` multiple times.

Comment: I don't have a clue how to do what you are asking, but your sample code looks very similar to some of the gotchas for reading a file from filestream.  Do a search for Jon Skeet and proper way to read a file and see if those same methods help you.  i.e. Looping over the bytes until they are all read.

Comment: The Serial Port Class has a small buffer so you will not get all the data in one Read().  You should put your Read() in a loop and call the Read() multiple times until you receive 21 bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. My only question is how would you know what the result should be? With a random number of bytes it seems impossible to know how many there should be. Unless I set the timeout. But I've read that doesn't always work.

Comment: Do you have a termination character in your protocol, e.g. CR/LF? If so you could use the `serialPort.ReadLine()` method. Also, I am assuming `GlobalVars.data_byte` is not a static variable... could you please confirm? If it is static you will have other issues on your hands.

Comment: There is no termination character. The data just stops. GlobalVars.data_byte us defined in public class GlobalVars as public static byte[] data_byte = new byte[100]; so, yes it is static.

Comment: OK, I just proved my suspicions correct. With ReceiveByteThreshold = 1 the ISR is called before all the Bytes are received. Therefore the .read doesn't see the all of them being sent. If I put a 5mS delay before doing the .read it gets all the bytes. I really do not like putting delays in programs. There must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One Time .. I was with almost the same situation.
Because like our friends said, sometimes it doesn't get all data at once.
Look the Received. I'll post my code, hope it helps:

```
var End = '\r'; //Last character for searching
int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);

RxString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
txtCodProd.AppendText(RxString);

if (RxString.IndexOf((char)End) > -1)
{
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(EndMethod));  //After Get all data, DoSomething    
} 

//RxString = _serialPort.ReadExisting(); // doesn't Work for all data
```